# To find the ratio of the greatest and smallest numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving

Given that the sum of squares of four positive integers is equal to $9\times2^{2015}$. Find the ratio of the greatest and smallest numbers among them.

**note** - I have been trying understand what number can I use as a modulus to find the remainder of a square number so that a pattern can be eshtablished regarding the problem. But I did not find any clue. So how should I look at the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's not clear that such an expression is unique (indeed, it isn't).  To get one such expression, note that $9\times 2=18=1^2+2^2+2^2+3^2$ and $N=9\times 2^{2015}=2^{2014}\times 18$ so we get one such expression easily, and the desired ratio is $3$.  It remains to consider alternate expressions.

Comment: Let $a=2^{1007}$. Then $9\cdot 2^{2015}=a^2(1^2+2^2+2^2+3^2)=a^2+(2a)^2+(2a)^2+(3a)^2=0^2+0^2+(3a)^2+(3a)^2$ and so on.

Comment: Look modulo $8$.  Can any of them be odd?